# How to speed up mysql query for most Joomla 1.5 mod_mostcomment

Tags: mysql, joomla, query-optimization

I have one query that is loading db so much and my hosting provider complains

```html
SELECT count(a.id),
       a.*,
       CASE
           WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(a.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", a.id, a.alias)
           ELSE a.id
       END AS slug,
       CASE
           WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(cc.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", cc.id, cc.alias)
           ELSE cc.id
       END AS catslug
FROM jos_chrono_comments AS com,
     jos_content AS a
LEFT JOIN jos_content_frontpage AS f ON f.content_id = a.id
INNER JOIN jos_content AS c ON f.content_id = c.id
INNER JOIN jos_categories AS cc ON cc.id = a.catid
INNER JOIN jos_sections AS s ON s.id = a.sectionid
WHERE (a.state = 1
       AND s.id > 0)
  AND s.published = 1
  AND cc.published = 1
  AND a.id = com.pageid
  AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= c.publish_up
GROUP BY (com.pageid)
ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 0,
                      10
```

it's Joomla 1.5 related and Chronocomments module for most commented in 30 days

I have some hints here https://goo.gl/0wF2ex but I am not so good to rewerite that in better way without using temp table

Looking for help to make that query not so heavy for mysql server, maybe eliminating group by or any hint will be usefull

Thanks,
K@m0

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possible answers, this is focusing on the database with no change to the PHP code.

## Explain query

With the MySQL `EXPLAIN` command, that you can use e.g. from phpMyAdmin, you can have optimization tips from MySQL itself, mostly related to adding indexes if required.

## Possible indexes

As a wild guess, I would make sure that all the following fields are indexed:

- jos_content.catid
- jos_content.sectionid
- jos_content.state
- jos_content_frontpage.content_id (if you have many items in frontpage)
- jos_categories.published (if you have many categories)
- jos_sections.published (if you have many sections)
- jos_chrono_comments.pageid

## Final notes

The `ORDER BY 1 DESC` part seems useless to me.

The increase of performance is really dependant from the size of your tables, so don't expect miracles. But it's definitely worth a try.